# Class Initialization

Tags: python, pyqt

I just have one small question about initialization. In Python, and when we do a Multiply inherit, what's the difference between call the super function of child class and call each of them separate?

```
classA(B,C)

super(A,self).__init__()

#---and---#

B.__init__(self)
C.__init__(self)
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you mean to place `super()` *inside* of `A`'s `__init__()` method? Please fix your code, this code will generate the (obvious) IndentationError, as well as a NameError for `classA`.

Comment: Oh i'm sorry. I just wrote it for short :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference is that if classes B and C have a common ancestor, with the `super()` call, that ancestor's `__init__()` will only be called once. By calling the parents' `__init__()` method explicitly as in your example, the common ancestor's `__init__()` will end up being called twice.

You can read about how `super()` accomplishes this from [Guido's explanation](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/06/method-resolution-order.html).

Below is a demonstration of the explicit call to the parents' `__init__()` and how it calls the common ancestor twice:

```
>>> class A(object):
...   def __init__(self):
...     print "A"
... 
>>> class B(A):
...   def __init__(self):
...     A.__init__(self)
...     print "B"
... 
>>> class C(A):
...   def __init__(self):
...     A.__init__(self)
...     print "C"
... 
>>> class D(B,C):
...   def __init__(self):
...     B.__init__(self)
...     C.__init__(self)
...     print "D"
... 
>>> D()
A
B
A
C
D
<__main__.D object at 0x106de1d10>
>>>
```

And this is what happens with `super()`

```
>>> class A(object):
...   def __init__(self):
...     print "A"
... 
>>> class B(A):
...   def __init__(self):
...     super(B,self).__init__()
...     print "B"
... 
>>> class C(A):
...   def __init__(self):
...     super(C,self).__init__()
...     print "C"
... 
>>> class D(B,C):
...   def __init__(self):
...     super(D,self).__init__()
...     print "D"
... 
>>> D()
A
C
B
D
<__main__.D object at 0x10d34ec90>
>>>
```